# How to run commands in Openbox?

Tags: lxde, openbox

I have installed new `openbox` but I don't know how to get the commands executed for an application or directory.

I can't add any application if don't know command of that?

Answer (score 7):

First after installing openbox, copy the base configuration of openbox to  your own home directory for customization purpose:

```
mkdir -p ~/.config/openbox
cp /etc/xdg/openbox/* ~/.config/openbox/
```

now you have a basic configuration to built upon it.

---

#### Using command:

Install `gmrun` or `dmenu` from `suckless-tools` package.

```
sudo apt install gmrun
```

now open `~/.config/openbox/rc.xml` file using an editor:

```
nano ~/.config/openbox/rc.xml
```

search for "keybind" and add something like:

```
<keybind key="A-F2">
   <action name="Execute">
     <command>gmrun</command>
   </action>
</keybind>
```

to this file, after that run `openbox --reconfigure`, now using <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> a prompt asks you for command:

[image]

then you can type in your desired command and press <kbd>enter</kbd> to run it.

---

## Using GUI

A program which I prefer is `xfce4-appfinder`, install it using:

```
sudo apt install xfce4-appfinder
```

now like before add a keybinding for the command `xfce4-appfinder`, something like:

```
<keybind key="A-F3">
   <action name="Execute">
     <command>xfce4-appfinder</command>
   </action>
</keybind>
```

every time you press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F3</kbd> a window look like this will be open:

[image]

You can explore programs installed on your machine by category or even searching for their name.

#### Using right click menu

open this file:

```
nano ~/.config/openbox/menu.xml
```

add these lines into it:

```
<menu id="/Debian" label="">
        <item label="New Item">
                <action name="Execute">
                        <execute>command</execute>
                </action>
        </item>
</menu>
```

and run:

```
openbox --reconfigure
```

now each time you right click anywhere in your right click menu you will have a item named "Debian" which contains all installed applications on your Ubuntu.

Comment: Please also mention that `openbox --reconfigure` should be run after each edit to rc.xml or menu.xml is made for the changes to immediately take effect.

Comment: `now each time you right click anywhere in your right click menu`: can you explain: if I click right somewhere, the menu has `debian` as entry?